# How to match elements between dataframes based on conditions in base R or dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge, match, left-join

I am trying to match these two data frames, nCode and grpRnk, as illustrated below.

[image]

Using the code shown at the bottom, I've been able to get the below output whereby the last column on the right shows the correct values, but I don't need those extra columns from `grpRnk$Name` through `$subGrp` (columns 6 -10) and I had specified a name for the last column of `grpRnk` but I instead get `$grpRnk`. Am I using this `merge()` function correctly? Is there a more correct or efficient way to do this sort of multi-factor matching?

```
  Name  Group nmCnt seqBase subGrp grpRnk$Name $Group $nmCnt $seqBase $subGrp $grpRnk
  <chr> <dbl> <int>   <int>  <int> <chr>        <dbl>  <int>    <int>   <int>   <int>
1 R         0     1       1      0 B                0      1        1       0      NA
2 R         0     2       2      0 R                0      1        1       0      NA
3 B         0     1       1      0 R                0      2        2       0      NA
4 R         0     3       3      0 R                0      3        3       0      NA
5 X         1     1       1      1 X                1      1        1       1       1
6 X         1     2       1      2 X                1      2        1       2       1
```

The code:

```
library(dplyr)

myDF1 <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

nCode <-  myDF1 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(nmCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(seqBase = ifelse(Group == 0 | Group != lag(Group), nmCnt,0)) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = na_if(seqBase, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(seqBase) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = match(seqBase, unique(seqBase))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(subGrp = as.integer(ifelse(Group > 0, sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Name[1:x]==Name[x] & Group[1:x] == Group[x])),0))) 

grpRnk <- nCode %>% select(Name,Group,nmCnt) %>% 
  filter(Group > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Name,Group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(Group)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(nmCnt) %>%
  mutate(grpRnk = dense_rank(nmCnt)) %>%
  select (-nmCnt)

nCode %>% mutate(grpRnk = merge(nCode,grpRnk, by=c("Name","Group"), all.x=T))
```

Comment: Using `merge` inside a `mutate` is not right; typically `merge` is a verb of its own, or you can opt for the `dplyr`-variants of it: `left_join`, etc. Can you please show what you *expect* given your two datasets?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this! What I expect given the 2 datasets is shown in the image in my OP, where I show in bold an added column for "grpRnk". Also shown in that right-most column when running the merge code in my OP, the column $grpRnk. A column of all NA's except the last 2 rows which are each = to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what column you want to extract into your newly created `grpRnk` column. You can achieve this by adding `$grpRnk` to the end of your `merge()` statement.

Here I have first a solution with `merge()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myDF1 <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("R","R","B","R","X","X"),
    Group = c(0,0,0,0,1,1)
  )

nCode <-  myDF1 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(nmCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(seqBase = ifelse(Group == 0 | Group != lag(Group), nmCnt,0)) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = na_if(seqBase, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(seqBase) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = match(seqBase, unique(seqBase))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(subGrp = as.integer(ifelse(Group > 0, sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Name[1:x]==Name[x] & Group[1:x] == Group[x])),0))) 

grpRnk <- nCode %>% select(Name,Group,nmCnt) %>% 
  filter(Group > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Name,Group) %>% 
  slice(which.min(Group)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(nmCnt) %>%
  mutate(grpRnk = dense_rank(nmCnt)) %>%
  select (-nmCnt)

nCode %>% mutate(grpRnk = merge(nCode,grpRnk, by=c("Name","Group"), all.x = TRUE)$grpRnk)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   Name  Group nmCnt seqBase subGrp grpRnk
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 R         0     1       1      0     NA
#> 2 R         0     2       2      0     NA
#> 3 B         0     1       1      0     NA
#> 4 R         0     3       3      0     NA
#> 5 X         1     1       1      1      1
#> 6 X         1     2       1      2      1
```

However, you can achieve the same result using only `merge()` like this:

```r
merge(nCode,grpRnk, by=c("Name","Group"), all.x = TRUE)
#>   Name Group nmCnt seqBase subGrp grpRnk
#> 1    B     0     1       1      0     NA
#> 2    R     0     1       1      0     NA
#> 3    R     0     2       2      0     NA
#> 4    R     0     3       3      0     NA
#> 5    X     1     1       1      1      1
#> 6    X     1     2       1      2      1
```

And here is another solution using `left_join()` from the `dplyr` package:

```r
left_join(nCode, grpRnk, by = c("Name", "Group"))
#> # A tibble: 6 × 6
#>   Name  Group nmCnt seqBase subGrp grpRnk
#>   <chr> <dbl> <int>   <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1 R         0     1       1      0     NA
#> 2 R         0     2       2      0     NA
#> 3 B         0     1       1      0     NA
#> 4 R         0     3       3      0     NA
#> 5 X         1     1       1      1      1
#> 6 X         1     2       1      2      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'll go with left_join given its simplicity and r2evan's comment. I won't forget this, left_join is very important